# Remove what is second parentheses of a string vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, trim

i have a string like this

```
blabla (lo-g) (kk-jj)
```

i want to make it like this

```
blabla (lo-g)
```

but when it's already like this in vb.net

```
blabla (lo-g) with one parenteses
```

just let it as and is

thanks

Comment: What would you want to happen with strings like `blabla (lo-g) with (kk-jj) trailing` and `blabla (lo-g) (kk-jj) trailing`

Answer (score 1):

Regex is a powerful, flexible, and configurable tool for doing things like this.  It's not entirely clear from your question exactly what rules need to be followed in other variations for the input, but here's an example which works for the inputs you specified:

```
Dim input As String = "blabla (lo-g) (kk-jj)"
Dim pattern As String = "(?<=^[^(]*\([^)]*\)\s*)\([^)]*\)(?=\s*$)"
Dim output As String = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "")
```

However, that will not remove the second set of parenthesis for inputs like these:

```
blabla (lo-g) blabla (kk-jj) blabla
blabla (lo-g) (kk-jj) blabla
```

To handle variations like those, you could use a pattern like this:

```
Dim input As String = "blabla (lo-g) with (kk-jj) trailing"
Dim pattern As String = "(?<=^[^(]*\([^)]*\)[^(]*)\([^)]*\)(?=[^(]*$)"
Dim output As String = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "")
```

Answer (score 1):

i want to thanks steven for his answer but for those who can't handle regex (like me)
here's a simple stupid method

```
Dim res As String = String.Empty

        Dim check As Boolean = False

        For Each letter In teamname
            If letter = "(" Then
                If check = True Then
                    Exit For
                End If
                check = True
            End If
            res &= letter

        Next

        Return res
```

good luck

Comment: This works great for a very specific case and if you are sure you strings will conform to this case it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to avoid RegEx, this is a simpler/easier to read version *I think* of what you're trying to accomplish with your loop through each character.  Basically you split the string into an array using the ( character as the dividers.  So, they need to be re-added but it's nominal since you only need the 1 included (or not).

Essentially splitting your string into this:
"blabla (lo-g) (kk-jj)"

Array(0) = "blabla "
Array(1) = "lo-g) "

So, Array(0) & "(" & Array(1) = "blabla (lo-g)", or simply returns the whole string if it counts <= 1 ( character

```
    Dim SplitText = text.Split("(")

    If SplitText.Length > 1 Then
        Return String.Format("{0}({1}", text.Split("(")(0), text.Split("(")(1))
        'This may be easier for you to read, though:
        'Return text.Split("(")(0) & "(" & text.Split("(")(1)
    End If

    Return text
```